# How can I customize a Collectionview with a large cell and two small cells in a single row?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm trying to customize a `UICollectionView` so that there is a large cell and two smaller cells on a single row like shown in the picture below.

What I've got so far is 2 cells on a row. I accomplished the dynamic width calculations by:

```
rowWidth = widthPerItem / 1.50 - 5
        if indexPath.item % 2 != 0 {
            rowWidth = (widthPerItem - (widthPerItem / 1.50)) + widthPerItem - 5
            widthIndex += 1
        }
```

I tried to split the second cell in the row in half, thinking the third cell would go below the second one, but that wasn't the case.

[image: Current]

What I want:

[image: Expected Design]

Comment: @ZGski edited the question

Comment: Custom `FlowLayout` or you specify the cell sizes in sizeForItem by using an algorithm.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest